# Get all external IPs from Google Kubernates

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Im trying to get all the external IPs that the pods from kubernetes can use, its possible consult this in console?

Answer (score 3):

Pods have no external IP as the nodes are responsible for communication with the Internet. You can check this diagram for more details[1].

It seems what you're referring here is the internal IP address range that the pods can use.

You can get this information by navigating to `☰` > `Kubernetes Engine` > `Clusters`.

Click the name of your cluster, then scroll to "Networking". It will show you the "Cluster pod address range (default)". You can check this documentation[2] for more details.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#pods

[2] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#ip-allocation